# Android Webview not loading website until I change the app package name

Tags: android, webview

i have a webview app on playstore and its stop loading website.there is no SSL issue but now it's not working until I change the app package name to another new package name.can you please help. if i change the package name then i cant update my current play store app.
Thanks

Comment: Just curious, what is your package name.

Comment: Have you tried searching for that "required" package name in your project? See if it's declared anywhere?